# C++ Unexpectedly Exiting For Loop

Tags: c++

I am working through Andrew Koenig's *Accelerated C++*, and one of the exercises asks to write a program to output two columns, one of integers up to some *maxInt* and the other of their squares. Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>


using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::setw;
using std::to_string;
using std::string;


int square(const int n)
{
    return n*n;
}

int main()
{
    // loop until maxInt
    const int maxInt = 1000;

    // use the length of maxInt and its square to comptue width later on
    const int maxIntSize = to_string(maxInt).length();
    const int maxIntSquareSize = to_string(square(maxInt)).length();

    for (int i = 1; i != maxInt + 1; ++i) {

        const int j = square(i);

        // we need iSize to compute the width
        const int iSize = to_string(i).length();
        const int width = maxIntSize + maxIntSquareSize + 1 - iSize;

        cout << i << setw(width) << j << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

My problem is that the program is inconsistent. Sometimes it works as I expect, other times it stops printing prematurely. Furthermore, when it doesn't do what I expect, the behavior is rather unpredictable. Could anyone let me know what I'm doing wrong?

(Also, I am new to C++, so any general advice is appreciated.)

Comment: I have tested your code on Visual Studio 2017, on Windows 10. (x86 mode), it never failed. Always runs up to 1000 and then quits. Which OS are you using and how exactly it fails?

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9d2159fa077e1d4a)

Comment: If you do a new program an just put `std::cout << sizeof(int);` in `main`, what do you get?

Comment: @NathanOliver I got 4

Comment: Did you copy-paste the actual code you have? Or did you rewrite it into the question? If your real program is as short as this, copy-paste it instead, by rewriting it you might inadvertently fix the problem. If it's bigger then try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that actually exhibits the problem, and copy-paste it into the question.

Comment: @TuğberkKaanDuman I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, 64 bit. As mentioned, sometimes it works as expected. Last time I ran it, it printed up to "285 8122" and then exited with exit value 0.

Comment: So when it does quit prematurely, did you use a debugger to look at the state of all the variables?

Comment: Perhaps begin by simplifying the code. Gather the strings together prior to printing them to cout. Remove the const from every variable. Are you running the program with any flags? Also, declare the variables outside of the for loop as they are used repeatedly. Also, add the maxIntSize, maxIntSquareSize and the +1 outside the for loop as they do not change values.

Comment: Would a simple `g++ yourprogram.cpp -o yourexecutable` and `./yourexecutable` still fail? It looks like there's no issues with your code and it works as intended, on my side.

Comment: what is value of maxInt you are using ? Did you always use 1000 ?

Comment: Another point, but should not be a problem here (at least with the code you show) using `!=` as condition in a loop could be problematic. If you, maybe by mistake, modify `i` more than once or by more than one, then such comparison might not work. If looping up to a specific value, use either `<` or `<=` for comparison.

Comment: Wait are you saying you get values up to `2858122`? For `i` or for `j`? Not that it matters it's still way off what you should get with the code you show (with `maxInt == 1000` and `square(maxInt) == 1000000`).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude No, it prints all integers in two columns, correctly, up to 285. On the last line, it prints 285 in the first column and 8122 in the second column. Then it exits.

Comment: Then again: With the actual program you *show*? If you copy the program you show, and paste it into a new source file, build that source file like you build your failing program, and then run it, do you still have the same problem?

Comment: Works on my machine.  Is the code provided the exact same code that is exhibited the problem?

Comment: @eljay Yes, exact same. I copy and pasted.